# The Meaning Of OEMData

Tags: windows, registry

Look at this registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM\VID_0079&PID_0011]
"OEMName"="USB Gamepad "
"OEMData"=hex:00,00,00,10,0a,00,00,00
```

As you can see, there is key named OEMData and it has a binary (hex) value, it is related to joystick, I know that the numbers of joystick's buttons is stored here, I mean for example if a joystick has 10 button it is written here, I want to know how can I find out it, I mean I want to know this joystick has how many buttons.

Really need it so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the registry, use a documented API function.  Like [IDirectInputDevice8::GetCapabilities()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectinputdevice8.idirectinputdevice8.getcapabilities%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The returned DIDEVCAPS.dwButtons tells you how many buttons are available on the joystick.

Comment: Thanks, but really want to use registry, I'm using Autopaly media studio and need to read from registry, can you help please?

Comment: Really if I can find out that the target joystick is 2-axis (2 analog) or not is enough, possible via registry and oemdata?

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of OEMData is described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/KB/163353